# QuickBooks with Joomla integration

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I need to integrate our website in Joomla and quickbooks by importing the customer, invoice data from joomla site to Quickbooks. I am using Quickbooks pro 2014 on windows machine. I see there is QuickBooks PHP DevKit available by ConsoliBYTE.  By searching on stackoverflow, I see people have used this toolkit to perform the data import(customer creation) into QuickBooks. I need to know what all Quickbooks functionality can be achieved using this php toolkit. That is what it can and cannot do.  Is it build on QB SDK?

For example I have scenario where I need to import customers and need to add them as customer jobs. So does phpdevkit supports job creation? If yes then how do I find the xml for that in phpdevkit quickbooks library? So probably there will be more such similar requirements coming from end user in future and I need to consider these  facts while designing the solution using php toolkit. I do not want a solution which is limited to only few or specific functionality. I have read the QB SDK and it is mentioned that SDK can be used with .NET, java. both solution goes with webconnector. SDK can perform almost all the functions as supported in quickbooks UI. So I am confused which one I should pick PHP toolkit by ConsoliByte or .Net/Java based. Language is not a concern for me. My aim is to look for solution flexible and capable to cover maximum QB functionality which includes customer creation, invoice creation, adding customer job and updating the customer/invoice on every synchup as well as limitation which the solution poses must be known before implementation.
So along with what QuickBooks PHP DevKit can or cannot do, I need to know its difference from Java/.Net based QB SDK (Not language PHP or VB.NET/Java but core framework)?
I tried searching it over stackoverflow and google but could not found this information. I appreciate any inputs shared.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to know what all Quickbooks functionality can be achieved using this php toolkit.

The full list is much too long to post here. As a basic overview:

- Automatically send orders placed on your website to QuickBooks Online or QuickBooks for Windows
- Charge credit cards using the QuickBooks Merchant Service
- Connect to Intuit Anywhere / the Intuit Partner Platform and the v3 APIs
- Get access to QuickBooks reports
- Pull information out of QuickBooks and display it online
- Connect to all Microsoft Windows versions of QuickBooks
- Connect to QuickBooks Online Edition
- etc. etc. etc.

More details available here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

For QuickBooks FOR WINDOWS, you can see the full list of operations supported by clicking the "Select Message" drop-down in the OSR:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

For QuickBooks ONLINE, you can see the full list of operations supported here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services

> Is it build on QB SDK?

Yes.

> So does phpdevkit supports job creation?

Yes. Anything the QuickBooks SDK supports you can do.

> If yes then how do I find the xml for that in phpdevkit quickbooks library?

Use the QuickBooks OSR I linked to above. Search for CustomerAdd (Jobs in QuickBooks are just Customers with a ParentRef defined).

We also have examples on our wiki:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests

And provide support via our forums:

- http://consolibyte.com/forum/

> I do not want a solution which is limited to only few or specific functionality.

Again, anything the QuickBooks SDK can do, can be done via the PHP DevKit.

> So I am confused which one I should pick PHP toolkit by ConsoliByte or .Net/Java based.

Joomla is written in PHP, so why the heck would you choose something written in another language...? It would be silly to try to tie .NET or Java in with your Joomla app/database...

> which includes customer creation, invoice creation, adding customer job and updating the customer/invoice on every synchup

All of that is certainly do-able.

> So along with what QuickBooks PHP DevKit can or cannot do, I need to know its difference from Java/.Net based QB SDK (Not language PHP or VB.NET/Java but core framework)?

The difference *is* the language. .NET is not PHP. PHP is not Java. Everything is just a wrapper around the QuickBooks SDK/COM API. The *only* practical difference in the language the stuff is written in.

Comment: Thanks Keith for your response and the php dev toolkit. Your detailed response has shown that with devkit I can perform almost every task.I will also like to stick to one technology for overall app rather than multiple and that's why only I questioned whether devkit will help me achieve the business functionality.I will try it out.Thanks

Comment: Keith I have accepted this as answer to my original question as whether it will be able to do what SDK allows. Now Since I have started looking it more on it, more questions are coming to my mind which I have raised on your forum.So please provide some insight to these too http://consolibyte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=23585#p23585

Comment: Keith, hope you are safe and doing well in. Can you please share the list of all allowed actions which can be done in QB Desktop via QB PHP SDK. I have been using invoice, item, payments, customer (add/mod/del) actions from last 7 years and these work perfectly. I want to know what else can be done via PHP SDK. In Quickbooks.php alot of functions are mentioned but not sure if all of these are supported for QB Desktop. Please guide. Also your site consolibyte.com looks to be under attack as there are alot of spam messages there and I am not able to search for required information.just FYI

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop